# Where should I ask about "punching hole into RFID card"

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

So I have this question about: **"How to easily and safely punch hole into RFID card"**.

> I have this 125khz RFID card and I would like to punch a hole in it
>   so I can have a thin string go through it, making my card to be able
>   to hang from my neck.
>
> Though I have no experience in punching hole to any sort of card, not
>   mentioning an RFID one.
>
> 1. Is it possible to punch a hole through the RFID card and still have it work properly?
> 2. How should I punch a hole through the RFID card safely, easily and using some cheap accessible tools (list of alternative ways to punch a
>      hole into RFID card is welcomed)
> 3. In the picture below, you can see my *RFID card* in front of a light source, showing the *antenna*. On the picture, I put a green
>      circle to the place where I *need* the hole to be (though I can make
>      the hole a little bit smaller as long as a double-string can pass
>      through). Is that a safe distance? Is the whole too big? Is there a
>      chance that it will break the card?
>
> **Picture:**
>
> [image: my RFID card]
>
> **Note:** please make your answers to be understandable for an average person like me (who is not deep into this field yet)

The issue is, I don't know where to post this question. The most suitable forum would be [RoboticsBeta](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) but they did not have any tags that would be applicable for me (there was no `rfid`, `rfid-card` or even `card` tags).

Can anyone help me to maybe create the appropriate tags at the [RoboticsBeta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGdKa.jpg) or redirect me to an appropriate forum?

Comment: no problem :) included an answer for you to consider

Comment: Almost tempted to suggest lifehacks. A badge holder would be the *sensible* solution, no holes needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can anyone help me to maybe create the appropriate tags at the RoboticsBeta or redirect me to an appropriate forum?

Seems that there is an [rfid](/questions/tagged/rfid) tag on [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/rfid/info), so I'd suggest you check the questions asked there to see if yours could fit.

Comment: Seems that OP asked his Q over EE.SE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/397935/194367

Comment: Heh, it even seems that such post reached HNQ :D *mission accomplished*

Comment: Didn't think that my first post at EE would be so active (614 views in 4 hours). Anyway, thanks for the help. I have also credited you at the [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397935/punch-a-hole-into-a-rfid-card-125khz) :)

Comment: Always a pleasure to help :) as a suggestion (completely unrelated to punching holes), why not use something that could glue or stick to the card, so you don't have to punch it? Imagine something like a paper clip or fastener that clamps to your card. That way you won't have to punch it ;)

Comment: 1. Had already a template cover (to be stick on the card) with the holes already made | 2. the glue is not super reliable (and using excessive glue will damage the template cover or will create a bulk) | 3. Visually, I liked the card with the holes more :D